# Point out location in Google Map

Tags: php, google-maps

I am developing an application in PHP. I have latitude and longitute of few locations in Google Map. I want to point it those locations on google map.

How can i point it?

Comment: Thought about reading the API documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html take a look at the google api its very easy to work with